# "Unauthorized" error in adding SSL Certificate to an AWS EC2 instance using Let's Encrypt

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, https, dns

I have a server running on Amazon Web Services as an EC2 instance and want to reach it in a secured manner (https).  I decided to use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), following [this](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) tutorial to install the SSL Certificates to the server (using the `--webroot` plugin type).  I used puTTY to reach the EC2 instance. In the final step, I was prompted to provide the domain name, wherein I keyed in the URL generated for the instance by AWS (not my own/masked domain name).

I get an Unauthorized error with a note saying

> FailedChallenges Failed authorization procedure abcd.efgh.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com (http-01) :urn:acme:error:unautorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://abcd.efgh.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/...

NOTE : abcd.efgh.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com is just an example of an AWS domain name I have provided for the question.

I also get a note following the error:

> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain contain(s)
>   the right IP address.

I'm not sure if this occurs because I'm directly using the AWS domain name and not a domain name that I own.

So will I get rid of this error, if I use a domain name that I own or is this issue because of something else that I need to add/change? Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is that you are trying to run Let's Encrypt with URL that is the Amazon EC2 instance's. You need to register a domain, point it at that EC2 instance, and then run Let's Encrypt with that domain name.

Helpful: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04